# UIPrintInteractionController crashed in iOS 14

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ios14

When presented in a standalone single view application the following code works a treat.

But when I try to load the same code on UISplitViewController the application crashed,But this code works like a charm in iOS 13 application.But In iOS 14 it is going to crash and following exception occur:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception '**UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', 

reason: 'child view controller:<UIPrintPreviewViewController: 0x10394fa00> 
should have parent view controller:<CXSTransactionSelectionViewController: 0x10389e400> 
but actual parent is:<UIPrintPanelTableViewController: 0x103808200>'**
```

Code I am using :

```
- (UIViewController *)printInteractionControllerParentViewController: (UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController {
  
   return [CXSCommon getParentController_iPhone];
}
- (void)Print 
{
 UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController 
 sharedPrintController];


     if(!controller){
         NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
         return;
     }
    
     UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
     ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
         if(!completed && error){
             NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %ld", error.domain, (long)error.code);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"complete");
         }
     };
    
     UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
     pic.delegate            = self;
     UIPrintInfo *printInfo  = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
     printInfo.outputType    = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
     printInfo.jobName       = @"My Job";
     printInfo.duplex        = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
     pic.printInfo           = printInfo;
    
     UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *textPrint = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p><h1>Hello World</h1></p><p><h2>Hello World</h2></p><p><h3>Hello World</h3></p><p><h4>Hello World</h4></p><p><h5>Hello World</h5></p><p><h6>Hello World</h6></p></body></html>"]];

     pic.printFormatter = textPrint;

     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // [controller presentFromBarButtonItem:self.addressButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
         
         [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
     }
     else {
         [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
     }
}
```

Comment: iOS 14 is still in beta. Probably correct place to ask this question is Apple forums, or a bug report.

Comment: But It is same working in another single view application which also run in iOS 14 beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by commenting the following code :

```
UITableView *tableView = [UITableView appearance];
  [tableView setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
  if ([[UITableView class ] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setSectionIndexBackgroundColor:)]) {
    [tableView setSectionIndexBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  }
  [tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];
  [tableView setTableHeaderView:[UIView new]];
```

I know this is strange, But its solved in my case.